# ASP.NET Web Pages vs ASP.NET Web Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I might be asking for the differences between apples and oranges here, but what are the differences between ASP.NET Web Pages and Web Applications/Web Sites? When creating a new web project, which should I use and what criteria should I consider when making a choice?

Also slightly unrelated, but what is the "future" of web projects in ASP.NET (i.e. is there another Windows technology other than the three that I should take into consideration?)

**EDIT:** To clarify, I do NOT mean the difference between ASP.NET Web Applications and ASP.NET Web Sites (unless Web Pages are somehow the same thing as one of the above.)

I mean ASP.NET Web Pages as detailed in MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fddycb06%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

As opposed to Web Applications/Sites as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please confirm if by "Web Pages" you mean http://www.asp.net/web-pages  or something else. Otherwise you will get a lot of confusing answers

Comment: You are correct that I mean ASP.NET Web Pages, not the difference between Web Application/Web Site. I've clarified above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in you trying to compare apple with oranges.

As **ASP.NET Web Applications** is file structure of your site, its behavior of compilation, producing assemblies and deployment method.

while Asp Web Pages are the User Interface for you site pages. You can have web pages with a Asp Net Application or Website project. Other option with ASP Net Web Pages, you can use [web forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx) or [MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Have their own advantages and disadvantages and depends on the situation and requirement of the site you are developing.

[Asp Net Web Pages details are here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/428509ah%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)